# Converting CIDR IP address ranges using ipaddress and output to a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with IPv4 and IPv6 CIDR IP address ranges (these can be split up if necessary) in a data frame. I am hoping to take those ranges and create a data frame with each address in the range, so I can join that with another data frame to do some filtering.

Using the ipaddress package, the function to expand a list is:

```
a = ip.ip_network('103.21.244.0/22')
    for x in a.hosts():
    print(x)
```

This yields a list for just this IP range. Does anyone know how to put in a series of CIDR ranges so I don't have to perform the above n times? If I put a reference to the data frame in place of the IP address above, I get a ValueError stating that it doesn't appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 network.

The secondary question, as a Python newbie, what do I need to do to get these expanded ranges into a list or data frame? I tried this:

```
a = ip.ip_network('103.21.244.0/22')
ip_list = [] #x for x in a.hosts()
for x in a.hosts():
    ip_list.append(x)
ip_list
```

And ended up with:

```
[IPv4Address('103.21.244.1'),
 IPv4Address('103.21.244.2'),
 IPv4Address('103.21.244.3'),
 IPv4Address('103.21.244.4'),
 IPv4Address('103.21.244.5'),
 ...]
```

I'm sure there is a better way than taking that output and regexing the IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ip.ip_network('103.21.244.0/22')
ip_list = [] #x for x in a.hosts()
for x in a.hosts():
    ip_list.append(x.compressed) # 
ip_list
```

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, I'm afraid you can't do it if the module doesn't support it, and I don't think it does [given the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_network). Python offers two ways to apply a method to a list besides the traditional for loop:

The [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) way, applies an operation to all the items of a list and returns a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) of the results:

```
def get_single_ip_from_cidr(cidr):
    # ...
cidr_list = ["10.0.0.0/8","192.168.0.0/16"]
results_generator = map(get_single_ip_from_cidr, cidr_list)
print(list(results_generator)) # Casting results_generator to list as you cant print generators directly
```

The pythonic way with [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def get_single_ip_from_cidr(cidr):
    # ...
results = [get_single_ip_from_cidr(cidr_addr) for cidr_addr in cidr_list]
```

About the second question, the list you get is a list of IPv4Address objects, you are just seeing a stringified representation of it. By using `help(ipaddress.IPv4Address)`, you can see that is has two attributes named `compressed` and `exploded` that both yield what you want (I'm assuming the difference between the two is only relevant in IPv6 where you can use `::` as a shorthand for a group of zeroes):

```
a = ip.ip_network('103.21.244.0/22')
ip_list = [addr.compressed for addr in a.hosts()]
```

Jeff's answer is doing exactly the same thing but is more verbose.

So, you can refactor your entire code to get all hosts from a list of networks like so:

```
import ipaddress as ip

def get_ip_from_cidr(cidr):
    return [addr.compressed for addr in ip.ip_network(cidr)]

cidr_list = ["192.168.0.0/30","10.0.0.0/26"] 
print([get_ip_from_cidr(cidr) for cidr in cidr_list])
```